# Null Pointer Exception when inserting to sqlite database - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I have two classes, one that adds tasks and one that adds categories. When adding a task you can associate that task with a category which is populated using a dropdown and the database enforces foreign keys by using triggers. I have got the application adding tasks correctly but I'm catching a null pointer exception with my add category class, and I'm having trouble pinning down where it is - I've looked in logcat but it hasn't been particularly helpful.

The class is as follows:

```
public class AddCategory extends Activity {
    EditText txtCatName;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcategory);
        txtCatName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCatName);
    }

    public void btnAddCat_Click(View view) {
        boolean ok = true;
        try {
            String name = txtCatName.getText().toString();
            DatabaseMethods cat = new DatabaseMethods(name);

            dbHelper.AddCategory(cat);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ok = false;
            CatchError(ex.toString());
        } finally {
            if (ok) {
                // NotifyEmpAdded();
                Toasts.ShowTaskAddedAlert(this);
            }
        }
    }

    void CatchError(String Exception) {
        Dialog diag = new Dialog(this);
        diag.setTitle("Add new Category");
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText(Exception);
        diag.setContentView(txt);
        diag.show();
    }

    void NotifyCatAdded() {
        Dialog diag = new Dialog(this);
        diag.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.add_category));
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText(this.getString(R.string.category_added));
        diag.setContentView(txt);
        diag.show();
        try {
            diag.wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            CatchError(e.toString());
        }
        diag.notify();
        diag.dismiss();
    }

}
```

If you need any more code then please just ask. Any help is much appreciated. Always helps to get a couple of more pairs of eyes on code to find errors :).

Comment: although you said `logcat` wasn't helpful, would you mind posting it anyway?

Comment: no stack trace?  Are you sure txtCatName is not null?

Comment: I agree with willytate, in the logcat you can see in wich particular line of code you are gettin that nullpointer Exception, very helpful ...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The logcat doesn't flag up the error, it's in a toast when I click the add button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `dbHelper` is being initialized, so I would suspect it would be returning as null.  Put a breakpoint at `dbHelper.AddCategory(cat);` and see if `dbHelper` is null.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used breakpoints before, is this just simply clicking toggle breakpoint on the line in eclipse? if so it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: In the editor, on the line you want your breakpoint, on the far left of the editor window there's a divider you can double click.  When you double click it will put a small circle there showing that a breakpoint has been set for that line of code.  When you debug your app through either the emulator or a device, Eclipse will go into debug mode when that line is crossed giving you more detailed information about the current objects being used.  You can hover over dbHelper and it will tell you if it's null or not.

Comment: thanks, ive done that but logcat is still outputting the same :(.

Comment: Did you try initializing dbHelper as I mentioned before?